# Rectangular text selection in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

From all the interpreter programs I have used, *cmd.exe* was unique in that it allowed you to select a rectangular block of text.

[image][Source](http://www.megaleecher.net/Copy_Paste_Text_Dos_Window#axzz4DB2I1Bp7)

Q1. Why did it use this method, as opposed to standard text-editor-like selection (like below)?

[image]

Q2.  Why do newer versions of cmd no longer use the rectangular selection model?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't give a definitive answer, since we are not the developers (so answers end up being based on opinions and guesses).

Comment: Tip: rather than pressing [Enter] to copy the selection to the clipboard, simply right-click!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we are not the developers, we are perfectly capable of *reading what the developers have written on the matter*.

- Adam Denning (2014-10-07).  *[Console Improvements in the Windows 10 Technical Preview](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)*.  Building Apps for Windows.  Microsoft.
- Scott Hanselman (2014-10-01). *[Windows 10 gets a fresh command prompt and lots of hotkeys](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows10GetsAFreshCommandPromptAndLotsOfHotkeys.aspx)*.
- Rafael Rivera (2014). *[New experimental console features in Windows "Threshold"](http://withinrafael.com/new-experimental-console-features-in-windows-threshold/)*.

This is not `cmd`.  `cmd` isn't a GUI program and isn't in charge of displaying console windows.  This is `conhost`, and two years ago a group of Microsoft developers decided to add a whole lot of improvements to it, one of which is "line selection".  They did so because they believe that they are addressing user desires — users like you who go around mumbling about the clunky copy and paste feature in Windows NT consoles.

There's a whole wish-list system, which Microsoft calls a "user voice", for the console subsystem, the command interpreter, and the new Windows NT Linux Subsystem.  Here are two fairly relevant wish-list entries from 2014:

- Joel Bennett (2014-10-02).  *[Switch between block and line text selection with a modifier](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/6513227-switch-between-block-and-line-text-selection-with)*
- Roeland (2014-10-01). *[Perhaps already in but: change console size more easily (80x25? c'mon :))](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/6510396-perhaps-already-in-but-change-console-size-more-e)*.

Comment: Thanks JdeBP, that's a lot of great references; though I didn't find an answer for Q1 at a glance. Added to weekend reading list.

Comment: @JdeBP: will your [FGA site](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA) be up again? (sry for off-topic as otherwise i have no way to contact you)

Comment: To keep a long story short: A backup currently is, but it doesn't have a high data rate.  It wasn't just me that was affected.  I am currently shopping around, for the first time in a very long time.  My country coming apart is causing some additional problems.  This is not a forum for discussing this; thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are not the developers, we cant give a definitive answer.  However, I can make an educated guess.

Starting off with Q2, this is just a better method.  When selecting data, you generally want to select the output, or the command you just entered, etc.  You want to select just the data you want, not everything else.  A rectangular box might force you into selecting white space, carriage returns, and other unwanted information.  This method allows you to capture all the data you need in one string.

As for Q1, well...  Im *guessing* they thought that it was a good idea as it matched drawing a selection in the Windows environment.  Like dragging a selection box on the Windows Desktop.  However, this method wasnt good, as if you captured more than one line and tried to paste it into a field that only takes one, problems occurred.  Either there would be not enough data, or to much.