# Excel reverse range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When doing a `MATCH` or anything that returns the first result in a range (say `A1:A10`) is there a way to reverse the range (`A10:A1`), such that the it effectively returns the last result? Currently, Excel "autocorrects" a range that is entered backwards (any idea why?).

I [found a fairly involved way](https://exceljet.net/formula/reverse-a-list-or-range) that uses `INDEX`, but isn't there a simple function like `REVERSE(A1:A10)`? If no, is there some reason that this is so hard that it is not built-in?

Comment: The answer is no and the reason; who knows.  you can do a Match on the last instance.  It is with an array formula.  `=Match(2,IF(A1:A10=yourvalue,1))` confirm with Ctrl Shift Enter

Comment: For something that seems as trivial as `REVERSE`, why do all Excel-related posts that deal with something like this require a complex array formula. I know @ScottCraner mentioned *who knows*, but I'm actually hoping someone here knows. That's actually my question -- a simple way to do `REVERSE`, or if it's not possible then why not? I'm guessing it's something to do with Excel's data layout?

Comment: The part of your question "why" is off-topic here, being primarily opinion based, we aren't from Microsoft, so we don't know the real reason.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I thought this [on my last question too](https://superuser.com/questions/1095868/rectangular-text-selection-in-command-prompt#comment1554113_1095868), but superuser has some super users having a lot of experience with Microsoft product internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we want to find the **last occurrence** of "goodforyour" in column **B**.  Try the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(B:B="goodforyou",ROW(B:B)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GarysStudent. Yes, for every individual function that needs something like this, there is a post on SuperUser. But I was asking about a general implementation of the `REVERSE` function described in the question (even better if it would not be an array formula).

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can find the **last** occurrence of a particular entry by using a characteristic of the `LOOKUP` function and a normally entered formula.

> ***If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value.***

So, using Gary's Student data as an example, you could use the normally entered formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B="goodforyou"),ROW(B:B))
```

Or, if you had something in Column C, and wanted to return the value in column C that matched the last "goodforyou" in column B:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B="goodforyou"),C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: From user [Philip](https://superuser.com/users/966927/philip): Ron, your formula works like a charm, but regardless of how hard I try to analyse it, I can't figure out WHY it works ... using as second Lookup argument an expression that is 1 divided by a comparison of a range is not corresponding to anything I can find in the Excel help.  Can you please shed some light on what makes this formula work? From that, I hope to learn a bit more on how to use similar functionality in other circumstances.  Thanks a lot

Comment: @Philip, see https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-lookup-function: "When lookup_value is greater than all values in lookup_vector, LOOKUP matches the last value."  `B:B="goodforyou"` is either true or false (1 or 0).  1/0 produces an error, which will never match, so only matches are in the running.  1/1=1, so all matches produce `1`.  The lookup value is 2, which is larger than all of the 1's, so it selects the last one.  This just takes advantage of a quirk in how LOOKUP operates.

Comment: @philip, to add to fixer1234 excellent explanation, I would add that `B:B="goodforyou"` will return an array like `{FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;...}`. Then `1/{theArray}` will look like `{#DIV/0!;1;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;1;1;#DIV/0!;...}`

Comment: "If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value."...but what if the lookup_vector is not sorted in ascending order?  Will it return the value prior to the first value that is greater than the search? Or the value prior to the last value that is greater than the search?  Or return an error?

Comment: @mpag I don't use it for that purpose. Suggest you try it and see what you get!